# What do I need to add to create a count vizualization

Tags: powerbi

I have a CSV file that has a list of wineries in one column and the state they are in, in another. What would I need to add to the data in Power BI in order to create a visualization that shows how many wineries are in each state?

For example, I have a CSV file that has 2 columns. One says the name of the winery and the other column has the state it is located in. I need to create a visual in Power BI that shows how many wineries are in each state. For instance, there are 999 wineries in California, ect.

I am very new to Power BI, so I do not understand all the codes and measures. So I am trying to figure out what needs to be added in order to show a visual like this.

Comment: It should read: What do I need to ask a comprehensible question so that others will be able to help me?

Comment: Did not realize that my question was not conprehensible. Maybe some constructive advice on what info needs to be added so that others can help would have been a more helpful comment.

Comment: Start here: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)